# how to do HTTP equivalent of multicast

Tags: http, networking

Lets say I have a  number of machines on the same subnet which have HTTP listeners on them listening on a well known port and from a client application I want to enumerate all available servers running this http listener.
Do I have any options except for going through all machines one by one and checking to see if the my service is up and listening?
I guess I am wondering if I can do anything clever like send all the machines a multicast and available servers can respond.
In general what sort of discovery schemes are um common when there are a bunch of http listeners involved

Answer (score 2):

HTTP is TCP based, which by definition doesn't support multicast.

So no, there's no way. You have to connect each one individually.

Comment: I don't think that is correct , if you wiki HTTP the relevant parts seems to be 

HTTP is an application layer protocol designed within the framework of the Internet Protocol Suite. Its definition presumes an underlying and reliable transport layer protocol,[2] and Transmission Control Protocol (TCP) is commonly used. However HTTP can use unreliable protocols such as the User Datagram Protocol (UDP), for example in Simple Service Discovery Protocol (SSDP).

Comment: which means that https://github.com/inorton/slp-sharp for Service Location Protocol might be just what I need. Thanks :-)

Comment: You mean http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTPU ? Well, that's only gonna work if your servers support HTTPU (doubt it :) ). And even if so, it does mean that they listen on regular HTTP.